# Debugging web application (aspx file) on VSCode

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-code, frontend, window

I've a web application. The main folder contains a file with .aspx extension. It does nothing else but redirects to a html page adding some parameters from a config file. The html is a simple web application which uses lots of JavaScript.
I want to debug it in VSCode, but I cannot. It has nothing to do with ASP.Net, but I cannot start aspx extension. I've installed the Live Server and I can run the HTML file, but it still doesn't work.
Is there any idea what the aspx file for? How can I skip it and debug directly the html file? The aspx file reads the web.config file, I guess I should use that too.
It works fine with IIS, but I would like to use break point to get a deeper insight into the JS files.

Comment: VS Code doesn't have the built-in ability to debug a Web Forms application as far as I'm aware (that's what .aspx is). You'll need to use actual Visual Studio to do this, not Visual Studio Code.

Comment: @mason is totally right. I had to realize it's an old code. So I removed the aspx file and the web.config and hardcoded some configuration parameter in the html. I started the vscode debugger (without live server) passing the html file (not the  url).